# How to fetch multiple data from two tables in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two table one is egg table and other one is rate disabled table.

Below I have share a screenshot so you can understand.
[image]

I want to fetch egg table data whose all the field is greater than 0 and for that particular field rate_status not disabled .

output should come like this:`

```
desi_egg =108, small_egg =55
```

(only two field should come because double_keshar_egg and medium_egg rate is greate than 0 and large_egg rate_status is disabled)

Here merchant_id is common for both table.

1. Can anyone has any idea

How to solve this proble by using sql query or hql query.
I am using MySql databse.

Answer (score 0):

You are suggesting some cumbersome query like this:

```
select concat_ws(', ',
                 (case when desi_egg > 0 and
                            not exists (select 1
                                        from testdb.rate_disabled rd
                                        where rd.merchant_id = e.merchant_id and
                                              rd.productName = 'desi_egg'
                                       )
                        then concat('desi_egg=', e.desi_egg)
                  end),
                 (case when desi_egg > 0 and
                            not exists (select 1
                                        from testdb.rate_disabled rd
                                        where rd.merchant_id = e.merchant_id and
                                              rd.productName = 'double_kesher_egg'
                                       )
                        then concat('double_kesher_egg=', e.double_kesher_egg)
                  end),
                 . . .
                ) as all_my_eggs
from testdb.egg e;
```